# How to integrate Interswitch Payment SDK for Android in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Pls , I want to integrate payment gateway using Interswitch Payment SDK for Android in codename one. I have the complete guide through  [this place](https://github.com/techquest/isw-payment-sdk-android#PaymentSDK)

I dont know how to go about this in codename one as the tutorial focused on android studio. PlS I really need this to work in codename one. Pls I need a guide about this to make it work in codename one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a native interface. See the link below, but also search on the CodenameOne website, as I recall there being a three-part series as well (it's a bit older now). Also, you might look at the Braintree CN1Lib as a similar example.

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-native-interfaces.html

Comment: thanks. Braintree is not supported in my country, I would have gone for that.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was probably the reason. I just suggested it as an example as I imagine there would be similarities.

Comment: This looks very similar to the braintree SDK. If you create a github cn1lib project and run into problems just post with the issues here or in the group and we'll try to help

Comment: pls try to refer me to the guide on  the braintree SDK to github cn1lib project. I will like to follow the steps for the interswitch SDK to github cn1lib  . thanks