# Runtime Exception in Purchase.pay

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone

Good day all, I have just completed my cn1 app and sent it to the buld server, everything seemed fine in the testing phase until I tried using the in-app purchase feature (purchase.pay(500,"$")). It reported an Internal application Error: java.lang.RuntimeException Unsupported
I really dont know what causes this

Comment: Kindly post the full StackTrace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir
it reported the error while I was testing on my real mobile device(an android 4.4)....not the simulator...The above mentioned error is all it reported
java.lang.RuntimeException Unsupported

Comment: Hook your device up with Eclipse having an Android plugin and use the debugger there to check the StackTrace.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the [developer guide section on in-app-purchase](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/monetization.html), you are using the manual purchase mode which is probably not your intention.

With in app purchase you need to work with product SKU's that you define in the various online stores. You don't pay an "amount", that only exists in manual purchases for physical goods which isn't as common. If you choose to use that then you should check out [Braintree](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/braintree-paypal-cn1lib.html).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, what I hope to achieve is a an online ticket purchase platform and yes, users should be able to pay for tickets through the app. From what I saw online, I am not really sure if Braintree has support for my target country, Nigeria.

Comment: Check out this person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418475/how-to-integrate-interswitch-payment-sdk-for-android-in-codename-one/45423847 Maybe interswitch worked for them. AFAIK nothing was published which is a shame...

Comment: Thank you diamond and shai for your response....my team has decided to use an online payment gateway which will redirect to a certain URL when payment is successful. Is there any way I can listen to URL changes in the web browser and perform a java task if its successful. Again thanks for your earlier responses

Comment: See https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#setBrowserNavigationCallback-com.codename1.ui.events.BrowserNavigationCallback-